# Rectangular UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton

I've read that you can make a UIButton rectangular by setting the cornerRadius, but is this only applicable to custom UIButtons? Is there a way to set the cornerRadius to zero on a default UIButton?

Comment: Um, it's not much but I've tried mybutton.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RoundedRectangle` Button type means that it would be rounded corners, I don't think it is possible to to set radius  to 0 for this button according to my experience,  however you could set the background image to it or use custom button type it is quite simple as you have mentioned in your question yourself.

Comment: In my opinion, answers should not be vague like these. Answers should be based on knowledge, not assumptions.

Comment: It is not vague answer, I have tried it myself sometime, I know it is not possible, but things are always being updated, people can be wrong, if I am wrong then it is your right to correct me,

Answer (score 2):

To make a UIButtonTypeRoundedRect type of UIButton rectangular, give the button a rectangular background image (e.g. with `setBackgroundImage:forState:`).